# Make first character of all the words in a string uppercase; if word has 3 characters or less, convert to ALLCAPS

Tags: php, string, cpu-word, casing

I trying to accomplish the following:

```
$string = "i want to convert this string to the following";
```

and convert it to something like this:

```
echo $string;
// I Want TO Convert This String TO THE Following
```

Thus:
Capitalize the First Letter of All Words in a string
and if a word is 3 characters or less, make the whole word Capitalized in the string.
How cant this be done with PHP?

Comment: So what have you tried already?

Answer (score 7):

A quick way (with regex):

```
$new_string = preg_replace_callback('/\b\w{1,3}\b/', function($matches){
   return strtoupper($matches[0]);
}, $string);
```

**EDIT:**

Didn't see you wanted to ucfirst the rest. This should do it:

```
$new_string = ucwords($new_string);
```

You can also combine them. :)

Comment: +1 but can you use `PCRE_EXTENDED` and add some inline comments to the Regex please? Makes it easier to grasp what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you could explode() your string and loop over it to check the length:

```
$array = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if(strlen($v) <= 3) {
        $array[$k] = strtoupper($v); //completely upper case
    }
    else {
        $array[$k] = ucfirst($v); //only first character upper case
    }
}
$string = implode(' ', $array);
```

Comment: This worked great for me! Thank you for the fast response. I am going to try the other solution as well. On line 4 $arrary must be changed to $array

Answer (score -1):

If a matched word character is followed by 1 or 2 word characters and then no more word characters, then convert all matched characters to uppercase; otherwise only convert the first word character to uppercase.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9fmRM))

```
$string = "i want to convert this string to the following";

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/\b\w(?:\w{1,2}\b)?/',
         fn($m) => strtoupper($m[0]),
         $string
     );
// I Want TO Convert This String TO THE Following
```

Comment: Please explain why this answer has a negative score.