# Add Wordpress shortcode to return space-delimited slugs with custom changes to word casing

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, uppercase

I tried combining my shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'MARKE', 'marke_shortcode' );
function marke_shortcode() {
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'marken');
    return ucwords($terms[1]->slug);
}
```

With the code I found right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4977241/20149572

Now I got this, but it didn't seems to work. What am I missing out?

```
add_shortcode( 'MARKE', 'marke_shortcode' );
function marke_shortcode() {
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'marken');
    $array = explode(' ', $terms);
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if(strlen($v) <= 3) {
            $array[$k] = strtoupper($v); //completely upper case
        }
        else {
            $array[$k] = ucfirst($v); //only first character upper case
        }
    }
    $string = implode(' ', $array); 
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: You need to return your `$string` at the end of the function?!

Comment: Updated the code. But it's not giving out anything.

Answer (score 1):

`$terms` is already an array so you dont need this line:

```
$array = explode(' ', $terms);
```

Try this snippet with it removed.

```
add_shortcode( 'MARKE', 'marke_shortcode' );
function marke_shortcode() {
    $arr = [];
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'marken');

    foreach($terms as $k => $v) {
        $term_name = $v->name;

        if(strlen($term_name) <= 3) {
            $arr[$k] = strtoupper($term_name); //completely upper case
        } else {
            $arr[$k] = ucfirst($term_name); //only first character upper case
        }
    }
    
    $string = implode(' ', $arr); 
    
    return $string;
}
```

You can also use `array_map` as an alternate option:

```
add_shortcode( 'MARKE', 'marke_shortcode' );
function marke_shortcode() {
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'marken');

    $arr = array_map(function($v){
        $term_name = $v->name;
        return strlen($term_name) < 4 ? strtoupper($term_name) : ucfirst($term_name);
    }, $terms);
    
    return implode(' ', $arr);
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for both ideas! Unfortunately none of them are working for me. Both are giving me an empty output. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Oh I forgot `get_the_terms` returns an array of objects.  Updated my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Much of that code can be consolidated.  See also my new answer on the page linked in the question body.

Like @mikerojas already mentioned, it looks like you failed to isolate the `slug` column values from the array returned from `get_the_terms()`.

When an array is passed to `preg_replace_callback()`, then an array is returned.

The refined script now only declares temporary variable `$m`;  all other processing is nested and therefore the final result string can be directly returned.

Code:

```
add_shortcode('MARKE', 'marke_shortcode');
function marke_shortcode() {
    return implode(
               ' ',
               preg_replace_callback(
                   '/\b\w(?:\w{1,2}\b)?/',
                   fn($m) => strtoupper($m[0]),
                   array_column(get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'marken'), 'slug')
               )
           );
}
```